# Batch normalization when batch size=1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization

What will happen when I use batch normalization but set `batch_size = 1`?

Because I am using 3D medical images as training dataset, the batch size can only be set to 1 because of GPU limitation. Normally, I know, when `batch_size = 1`, variance will be 0. And `(x-mean)/variance` will lead to error because of division by 0.

But why did errors not occur when I set `batch_size = 1`? Why my network was trained as good as I expected? Could anyone explain it?

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648509/batch-normalization-when-batch-size-1?noredirect=1#comment105458690_59648509) argued that:

> The `ZeroDivisionError` may not be encountered because of two cases. First, the exception is caught in a `try` catch block. Second, a small rational number is added ( `1e-19` ) to the variance term so that it is never zero.

But [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651396/how-to-calculate-batch-normalization-with-python/59654494?noredirect=1#comment105470721_59654494) disagree. They said that:

> You should calculate mean and std across all pixels in the images of the batch. (So even `batch_size = 1`, there are still a lot of pixels in the batch. So the reason why `batch_size=1` can still work is not because of `1e-19`)

I have checked the Pytorch source code, and from the code I think the latter one is right.

Does anyone have different opinion???

Comment: The `ZeroDivisionError` may not be encountered because of two cases. First, the exception is caught in a `try catch` block. Second, a small rational number is added ( `1e-19` ) to the variance term so that it is never zero. Check the source code for this.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Nothing is added in computing `variance` itself, but `1e-3` is added _to_ variance in normalizing, mainly for regularization

Comment: Updated answer; I missed an angle to your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> variance will be 0

No, it won't; `BatchNormalization` computes statistics only with respect to a *single axis* (usually the channels axis, `=-1` (last) by default); every other axis is *collapsed*, i.e. summed over for averaging; details below.

More importantly, however, unless you can explicitly justify it, I advise against using `BatchNormalization` with `batch_size=1`; there are strong theoretical reasons against it, and multiple publications have shown BN performance degrade for `batch_size` under 32, and severely for <=8. In a nutshell, batch statistics "averaged" over a single sample vary greatly sample-to-sample (high variance), and BN mechanisms don't work as intended.

**Small mini-batch alternatives**: [Batch Renormalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03275) -- [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450) -- [Weight Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07868)

---

**Implementation details**: from [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L137):

```py
reduction_axes = list(range(len(input_shape)))
del reduction_axes[self.axis]
```

Eventually, [`tf.nn.monents`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1220) is called with `axes=reduction_axes`, which performs a `reduce_sum` to compute `variance`. Then, in the TensorFlow backend, `mean` and `variance` are [passed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2191) to [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1373-L1434) to return train- or inference-normalized inputs.

In other words, if your input is `(batch_size, height, width, depth, channels)`, or `(1, height, width, depth, channels)`, then BN will run calculations over the `1`, `height`, `width`, and `depth` dimensions.

**Can variance ever be zero?** - yes, if every single datapoint for any given `channel` slice (along every dimension) is the same. But this should be near-impossible for real data.

---

**Other answers**: first one is misleading:

> a small rational number is added (`1e-19`) to the variance

This doesn't happen in computing variance, but it is added *to* variance when normalizing; nonetheless, it is rarely necessary, as `variance` is far from zero. Also, the epsilon term is actually defaulted to `1e-3` by Keras; it serves roles in regularizing, beyond mere avoiding zero-division.

---

**Update**: I failed to address an important piece of intuition with suspecting variance to be 0; indeed, the *batch statistics* variance is zero, since there is only *one statistic* - but the "statistic" itself concerns the mean & variance of the channel + spatial dimensions. In other words, the variance *of* the mean & variance (*of* the single train sample) is zero, but the mean & variance themselves aren't.

Comment: 'there are strong theoretical reasons against it, and multiple publications have shown BN performance degrade for batch_size under 32, and severely for <=8. In a nutshell, batch statistics "averaged" over a single sample vary greatly sample-to-sample (high variance), and BN mechanisms don't work as intended'

Can you please share some links to this articles and evidence generally ? 
Made me curious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "In other words, the variance of the mean & variance is zero, but the mean & variance themselves aren't." That's not how pretty much all practical BN implementations work. Stats are only computed once (collapsed over all dims except channels, as you rightly stated), not twice, as this wording seems to suggest (over all dims except batch, then over batch). The answer update is somewhat misleading and unwarranted, there is no need to compromise with the wrong side of the argument.

Comment: @amiasato I don't follow. The _sample_ variance of the statistics is zero for `batch_size=1`, as the variance of any single number (which is what results after collapsing all other dimensions) is zero. This was a possible root of confusion.

Comment: My point is that `batch_size` does not equate `n_samples` in any known BN implementation when there are other non-singular dimensions besides channels. `n_samples` is equal to the product of the collapsed axes' sizes. Clarifying this should be enough to clear the confusion.

Comment: @amiasato Fair, but I prefer to address the plausible "close but incorrect" intuition. Updated wording.

Answer (score 3):

> when batch_size = 1, variance will be 0

No, because when you compute mean and variance for BN (for example using `tf.nn.monents`) you will be computing it over axis `[0, 1, 2]` (assuming you have NHWC tensor channels order).

From "Group Normalization" paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08494.pdf
[image]

With batch_size=1 batch normalization is equal to instance normalization and it can be helpful in some tasks.

But if you are using sort of encoder-decoder and in some layer you have tensor with spatial size of 1x1 it will be a problem, because each channel only have only one value and mean of value will be equal to this value, so BN will zero out information.

Comment: This is mostly right and more terse than the most upvoted answer. The only thing I'd add is that, while in training time batchnorm with `batch_size=1` equals instance norm, in the original papers (and in most default configs) IN doesn't use running stats in test time, whereas BN does.