# What will happen if I use batch normalzation but set batch_size=1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

Because I am using 3D medical images as training dataset, the batch size can only be set to 1 because of GPU limitation. Some people told me that std dev will be 0 when batch_size = 1. And (x-mean)/std_dev will lead to error because of division by 0.

But why did errors not occur when I set batch_size = 1? Why my network was trained as good as I expected? Could anyone explain it?

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648509/batch-normalization-when-batch-size-1?noredirect=1#comment105458690_59648509) argued that:

> The `ZeroDivisionError` may not be encountered because of two cases. First, the exception is caught in a `try` catch block. Second, a small rational number is added ( `1e-19` ) to the variance term so that it is never zero.

But [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651396/how-to-calculate-batch-normalization-with-python/59654494?noredirect=1#comment105470721_59654494) disagree. They said that:

> You should calculate mean and std across all pixels in the images of the batch. (So even `batch_size = 1`, there are still a lot of pixels in the batch. So the reason why `batch_size=1` can still work is not because of `1e-19`)

I have checked the pytorch source code, and from the code I think the latter one is right.

Does anyone have different opinion???

Comment: [Batch normalization when batch size=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648509/batch-normalization-when-batch-size-1) this answer does not answer my question, I need more explanation.

Comment: You should not ask the same question more than once, that is why it is marked as duplicate. You can always edit your own questions.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have edit the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648509/batch-normalization-when-batch-size-1). Could you please help to 
 answer it again??